# opening / closing debug mode in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debug

Day by day, my application based on `asp core 2.0` while opening and closing `debug mode` lasts a long time. The first thing that came to my head is to clear and build the solution, but it still lasts longer than usual.

What else can I do to improve the debug mode process? App is running on `IIS Express` and `visual studio 2017`

**EDIT:**

it turned out that March 17 was an update related to Visual Studio coming from windows update. what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

**1st**
[safe mode from cmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2017)
**2nd**
[clean from cmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/clean-devenv-exe?view=vs-2017)

somebody recommended to me that to do it from cmd only!, but the second point I made manually from the `solution explorer` - and everything works as before!